# lm()$assign: what is it?

Tags: r, glm, lm, s

What is the `assign` attribute of a linear model fit?  It's supposed to somehow provide the position of the response term, but in practice it seems to enumerate all coefficients in the model.  It's my understanding that `assign` is a carryover from S and it's not supported by `glm()`.  I need to extract the equivalent information for `glm`, but I don't understand what the implementation does for `lm` and can't seem to find the source code either.  The help file for `lm.fit` says, unhelpfully:

> non-null fits will have components `assign`, `effects` and (unless not requested) `qr` relating to the linear fit, for use by extractor functions such as `summary` and `effects`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You find this in `help("model.matrix")`, which creates these values:

> There is an attribute "assign", an integer vector with an entry for
>   each column in the matrix giving the term in the formula which gave
>   rise to the column. Value 0 corresponds to the intercept (if any), and
>   positive values to terms in the order given by the term.labels
>   attribute of the terms structure corresponding to object.

So, it maps the design matrix to the formula.

Comment: ridiculous that this isn't mentioned _at all_ in `?lm`... had to spend 20 minutes tracking down where `assign` was coming from in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

The numbers from `$assign` represent the corresponding predictor variable. If your predictor is categorical with 3 levels, you will see the corresponding number (3-1) times in your `$assign` call. Example:

```
data(mpg, package = "ggplot2")
m = lm(cty ~ hwy + class,data = mpg)
m$assign 
  [1] 0 1 2 2 2 2 2 2
# Note how there is six 2's to represent the indicator variables
# for the various 'class' levels. (class has 7 levels)
```

You will see the quantitative predictors will only have one value (`hwy` in the example above), since they are represented by one term in the design formula.

Comment: Where's the code that calculates this field?  I couldn't find it so far.

Comment: Ah, I see the issue now. That is odd that the `$assign` is not in the source code for `lm` or `glm`.  I havn't found why yet, but I will keep looking.